# How can I access Webmin without a port?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, reverse-proxy

How can I use Apache on Ubuntu 11.04 and Webmin to set up a reverse proxy for Webmin's port 10000 to access it through a subfolder like www.example.com/webmin or webmin.example.com?

Answer (score 5):

You can use apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) to do this as a virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName webmin.yourdomain.com
    ProxyPass / http://servername.tld:10000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://servername.tld:10000/
<Proxy *>
    allow from all
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

or as a URL, add the following tto your main virtualhost configuration

```
ProxyPass /webmin/ http://servername.tld:10000/
ProxyPassReverse /webmin/ http://servername.tld:10000/
<Proxy *>
    allow from all
</Proxy>
```

the servername.tld could be localhost to an IP address

Answer (score 1):

There are specific configuration instructions over here: http://webmin.com/apache.html

You can either run it through Apache completely negating the webmin miniserver or run it through mod_proxy as Ignacio describes.

Answer (score 0):

[mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) will allow you to configure httpd as a reverse proxy to other web applications.